# Catalina Desktop Stacks Define New Kinds to Group By?

Tags: catalina, desktop, group

How can I define new "kinds" of desktop stacks in Mac OS Catalina, so I can easily 'group by kind' and get the kinds I want?

I've been using Catalina's desktop stacks to organize my desktop, grouping by kind, so images become a stack, movies become a stack, documents become a stack, etc.

This is a cool feature, except I'd like to define my own 'kinds,' so I get the groupings I want. I know I could group by tags, but then I'd need to tag files in order to add them to a group.

I suspect there's a config file somewhere on the system that maps file extensions to 'kinds', so that the OS knows how to manage file groups when files are grouped by 'kind'.

Anyone know where this file might be, how it's structured, or any other mechanism the OS has to redefine desktop stack kinds?

thanks!

Comment: File kind attribute, eh? Found a related question https://superuser.com/questions/263311/on-os-x-how-do-you-change-a-files-kind/981808#981808?s=52080e1701314951942e9bbb847096fb

Comment: Looks like the standard kinds that are being used are part of the OSX System library, so likely to change from version-to-version, etc. Is there a user-specific override/addendum?